How to use the "summarise" function in R to calculate the product of values in two columns?
In the orders_joined dataframe, I need to calculate the total revenue based on my sales and price by multiplying them together. And then I need to assign them to a new object - total_revenue.

I need to produce the table like this

Here is my attempt:
My code:
total_revenue <- orders_joined %>% 
  group_by(DESCRIP) %>% 
  summarise(num_units = n(),
            tot_rev = num_units*PPU) %>% 
  
  rename(item = DESCRIP)

head(total_revenue, 3)

My output:

In my output, the Egg Pudding and Lychee didn't show up, and all three items were Boba.
I think that there's something wrong with my "tot_rev = num_units*PPU" but couldn't figure out where went wrong.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post code or data in images. Use something like dput() so we can copy/paste the data into R for testing rather than having to retype everything from the image.

Well, only 3 rows show up because head(total_revenue, 3) asks for the first 3 rows. Look at total_revenue as a whole to answer the question of whether the other items are there or not.

If the other items are there, but it seems like the grouping didn't work, then you are likely accidentally using the wrong version of summarize from the plyr package, not the dplyr package, as explained in this FAQ.

An approach that renames the group in group_by. Using sum to get tot_rev since n() is the number of items per group . num_units * PPU will produce a vector that has the original length.
library(dplyr)

orders_joined %>% 
  group_by(item = DESCRIP) %>% 
  summarize(num_units = n(), tot_rev = sum(PPU))
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   item                       num_units tot_rev
   <chr>                          <int>   <dbl>
 1 Jasmine Milk; Boba                 2   13.5 
 2 Jasmine Milk; No Topping           2   12.5 
 3 Original Milk; Boba                2   11.5 
 4 Original Milk; Egg Pudding         1    5.75
 5 Original Milk; Lychee              3   17.2 
 6 Original Milk; No Topping          2   10.5 
 7 Oriqinal Milk; No Toooin           1    5.25
 8 Taro; Boba                         1    5.75
 9 Taro; Egg Pudding                  1    5.75
10 Taro; Lychee                       3   17.2

Data
orders_joined <- structure(list(order_no = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), item_no = c("T02", "T02", 
"B01", "T01", "J01", "B02", "J00", "T03", "J01", "B00", "B01", 
"B02", "J00", "T02", "B02", "B00", "B03", "B00"), DESCRIP = c("Taro; Lychee", 
"Taro; Lychee", "Original Milk; Boba", "Taro; Boba", "Jasmine Milk; Boba", 
"Original Milk; Lychee", "Jasmine Milk; No Topping", "Taro; Egg Pudding", 
"Jasmine Milk; Boba", "Original Milk; No Topping", "Original Milk; Boba", 
"Original Milk; Lychee", "Jasmine Milk; No Topping", "Taro; Lychee", 
"Original Milk; Lychee", "Original Milk; No Topping", "Original Milk; Egg Pudding", 
"Oriqinal Milk; No Toooin"), PPU = c(5.75, 5.75, 5.75, 5.75, 
6.75, 5.75, 6.25, 5.75, 6.75, 5.25, 5.75, 5.75, 6.25, 5.75, 5.75, 
5.25, 5.75, 5.25)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L
))


This is happening because there are duplicates in your output. The total_revenue table has as many rows as the orders_joined table, and each row is a group for the corresponding item of that row. The other items are in your table, they did not show up because you are selecting the first 3 rows to display in the head function.
You have to drop the duplicates by doing something like this:
total_revenue <- orders_joined %>% 
group_by(DESCRIP) %>% 
summarise(num_units = n(), tot_rev = num_units*PPU) %>% 
rename(item = DESCRIP)%>% distinct()


Its better to eliminate the problem (multiplication by the price inside summarise).

I usually use something like this;
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

set.seed(777)
df <- data.frame(desc = c("Boba", "Egg pudding", "Lychee"),
           ppu = c(5.75, 5.25, 5.75)) |> 
        slice_sample(n = 50, replace = T)

df |> group_by(desc) |> 
        mutate(num_units = n(),
               tot_rev = num_units*ppu) |> 
        distinct() |> 
        select(-ppu)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#> # Groups:   desc [3]
#>   desc        num_units tot_rev
#>   <chr>           <int>   <dbl>
#> 1 Boba               18    104.
#> 2 Egg pudding        20    105 
#> 3 Lychee             12     69

Created on 2024-04-10 with reprex v2.1.0
